# Office Open Xml :: Sections & Paragraphs

Tags: xml, ms-word, ms-office, openxml, docx

i created a valid .docx-Structure with an Application i wrote. Within the Word-File are `n..*` Sections. Each Section could have `n..*` Paragraphs.

**Scheme of a Section** - EDITED!!!

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:sectPr>
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1800" w:bottom="1440"
         w:left="1800" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="720"/>
      <!-- Properties for each Section (Margins etc.) -->
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <!-- Content-Area -->
</w:p>
```

I would love to add serveral Paragraphs to the Content-Area `<!-- Content-Area -->`.

**Structure of Paragraphs**

```
<w:p>
  <!-- Content -->
<w:p>
```

The problem is, it looks like Paragraphs within Sections are not working (but thats what i want!):

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:sectPr>
      <!-- Properties for each Section (Margins etc.) -->
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>First Paragraph</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>Second Paragraph</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:p>
```

The only thing i get work is, add Runs to a Section (but i want to have `n..*` Paragraphs!):

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:sectPr>
      <!-- Properties for each Section (Margins etc.) -->
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>First Paragraph</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

If i add new Paragraphs after the Section, i got a Pagebreak i don't wanna have.

So how to get it work?

Thx

Comment: Please use the [Edit] link below your question and include the WordOpenXML for the Section properties. There are different kinds of section breaks and you're probably inserting a "New Page" type rather than Continuous. Paragraphs cannot be within other paragraphs, they must be siblings, not children. Could you explain WHY you need continuous Sections?

Comment: Thx Cindy for the input. I would love to create a Document with Chapters, that's why i use Sections. You mean, i need to write a type insider the Section Properties?

Comment: Yes, w:type element with a val="continuous". BUT why do you want a section break for creating Chapters if you don't want each chapter to be forced to start on a new page? Section breaks exist to allow different margins, headers/footers, etc. within a document. Continuous section breaks are usually only used for changing the number of newspaper-type columns. Usually, Heading styles are used to make visible "sections", which can also be included in Tables of Content, cross-referenced etc.

Comment: I saw Cindy and i got it working. Thank you so much. No, it's exactly what i want. If i'll have some more question, may i ask you?

Comment: @Genealogy Please remember to upvote/accept answers that helped you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the type of section break is not specified Word will use the default setting (Page Layout/Page Setup/Layout/Section start) in the Word UI the document is opened in. By default, this is "New Page".

In order to use a different kind of section break the Word Open XML needs the `<w:type/>` tag with the val attribute. For a continuous section break:

```
<w:type val='continuous' />
```

Please note, however, that section breaks are primarily used to change page orientation, margines, header, footers, etc. within a single document. Logically, these things need to take effect for an entire page, so the Next Page type of section break is more common. Continuous section breaks are mostly used to change the number of newspaper-type columns.

If you do use continuous section breaks to designate "chapters" you need to be careful with headers and footers. Word will have trouble knowing which set of headers/footers to use on a page with a continuous section break - you may run into really strange issues if you're not very, very careful.

Answer (score 1):

The sectPr applicable to content follows that content; it does not precede it, as assumed in your question.